# Accessing equally named columns when looping over record

Tags: postgresql

I have a code block in which I am looping over a record that contains the join of two tables that have some equally named columns.

Now I need the values of two of these equally named columns, but I cannot get past the "missing FROM-clause entry for table "t1":

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.somecolumn = t2.somecolumn
LOOP
    INSERT INTO Table3 (column1, column2)
    VALUES (r.t1.someotherColumn, r.t2.someotherColumn);
          --^ error occurs here
END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Comment: You need to explicitly list all columns in your SELECT and give them an alias.

Comment: You need `SELECT t1, t2` in your loop head & reference columns as `(r.t1).someotherColumn` in your loop body. Otherwise you'll need to mention all columns explicitly & use alias to resolve ambiguities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `(record).column` syntax to refer to each of the composite types inside the record.

```
do $$
declare r record;
begin
    for r in
        select t1, t2
        from
            table1 t1
            join
            table2 t2 on t1.somecolumn = t2.somecolumn
    loop
        insert into table3 (column1, column2)
        values (((r.t1).someothercolumn), ((r.t2).someothercolumn));
    end loop;
end; $$;
```